# Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500 Back-off restarting failed container

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-health-check

I used kubeadm to deploy my Kubernetes dashboard.
When I tried to deploy the *nginx-ingress-controller* in my dev namespace with default service-account, I was getting *liveness probe* and readiness failing with status code.

nginx-ingress-controller image is

```
gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.15
```

I get the same error in the test namespace also.
In my logs it's showing

```
 Received SIGTERM, shutting down
 shutting down controller queues
I1201 00:19:48.745970       7 nginx.go:237] stopping NGINX process...
I1201 00:19:48.746923       7 shared_informer.go:112] stop requested
E1201 00:19:48.746985       7 listers.go:63] Timed out waiting for caches to sync
[notice] 22#22: signal process started
 shutting down Ingress controller...
 Handled quit, awaiting pod deletion
I NGINX process has stopped
 Exiting with 0
```

Why am I getting failures in cluster scope; where is my failure?

Comment: seems to be liveness or readiness probes are not configured properly. Adding Deployment info can help to debug this.

Comment: apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-dev-controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress-controller
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      serviceAccount: default
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller  , image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.15

Comment: imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1

Comment: this the file i have used.. please help me to debug this

Comment: args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-backend
            - --v=2
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
sorry forget to paste. yaml file

Comment: i have small issue.... i changed container name as jnlp in the pod template.. after changing this my pod is running asusual in kubernetes, but jenkins not able to pick that slave pod.. getting    1.    slave kubernetes-gf45j is offline can any one help me plzz dying with this issue

Comment: Did you find the root cause? Could you share if you made it please? There are some troubleshooting steps in this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473883/kubernetes-pod-failed-with-back-off-restarting-failed-container) `$ kubectl get events` could help in the troubleshooting process

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely adding too little resources try removing the resources for debugging